# Equivalent results with gradients

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding why two methods for calculating the gradient seem to be giving different answers:

Let's assume $\nabla{\vec{a}} = 0$, and we are working in spherical coordinates

Method 1:

$\nabla\frac{(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{a})}{r^2} = \nabla\frac{(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{a})}{r^3}$

$=\frac{1}{r^3}\nabla(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{a})+(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{a})\nabla\frac{1}{r^3}$

$=\frac{\vec{a}}{r^3}-\frac{3(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{a})\hat{r}}{r^4}$

Method 2:

$\nabla\frac{(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{a})}{r^2} $

$=\frac{1}{r^2}\nabla(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{a})+(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{a})\nabla\frac{1}{r^2}$

$= -\frac{2(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{a})\hat{r}}{r^3}$ (Since gradient of unit vector's magnitude is 0)

Throughout I have been using the product rule for gradients, but I think I applied it the same way in both cases.  I'm not sure if there is some algebraic manipulation I can do to get these answers equal to each other.  I know that in general $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}) \neq (\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\cdot\vec{c}$, or the two expressions would be easy to equate.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: "Since gradient of unit vector's magnitude is 0". This isn't relevant. This is what that term should be: $$\begin{aligned} \nabla(\hat r\cdot\vec a) &= \nabla\frac{\vec r\cdot\vec a}r \\ &= \dot\nabla\frac{\dot{\vec r}\cdot\vec a}r + \dot\nabla\frac{\vec r\cdot\dot{\vec a}}r + \dot\nabla\frac{\vec r\cdot\vec a}{\dot r} \\ &= \frac{\vec a}r + 0 - \frac{\vec r\cdot\vec a}{r^2}\hat r \end{aligned}$$ This is a sort of generalized product rule; the dots indicate what is being differentiated. You'll see that with this correction method 2 lines up with method 1.

Comment: Thank you! Just so I understand, why do we need to rewrite rhat? Can’t we just take its derivative directly like you have with the r vector in the first term?

Comment: $\hat r\cdot\vec a$ is essentially the angle between $\hat r$ and $\vec a$. Why do you expect that angle to be constant regardless of how $\hat r$ varies? That's what it would take for $\nabla(\hat r\cdot\vec a)$ to be zero. Now, I don't know how to take that gradient directly, so I expanded $\hat r = \vec r/r$ because I know that $\nabla(\vec r\cdot\vec v) = \vec v$ for constant $\vec v$, and because I know how to do $\nabla a/r$ for constant $a$.